# Why is this shadow not working in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

To be honest, I don't know how to ask this strange behaviour on shadows because I'm using the CSS standards and, by my surprise, it's not working properly:

Take a look at this style:

```
.light.boxed {
/*  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03),
        0 0 0 1px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.06);*/
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03),
        0 0 0 1px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.06);
/*  box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03),
        0 0 0 1px rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.06);*/
}
```

It's supposed that Firefox Dev Edition displays the shadow taking the values from the `-moz-box-shadow`, but it doesn't. It displays nothing. It takes the value directly from `box-shadow`.

Moreover, when I uncomment `box-shadow`, it displays the shadow on Firefox, BUT when I scrolldown the page, it shows some irregularities in the render; I mean, at some point the shadow is darker, and at the end it's lighter again. It seems that Firefox doesn't render properly the **rgba** colors (only when the blur parameter is 0 and you have to scrolldown).

[image: shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWVQN.png)![shadow]

Is it a known bug? Do you know a solution for it?

This is the HTML:

```
<body class="light boxed"></body>
```

And more CSS:

```
.boxed {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Look an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardbm/d7d4u5rf/
You need to open it in Firefox to see how the shadow doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and other relevant CSS?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody, I created a jsfiddle for this. It's better, faster and cleaner to understand the strange behavior. It was supposed that `-moz-box-shadow` was enough to display a shadow in Firefox, but this jsfiddle shows the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gecko 13 (Firefox 13) removed support for -moz-box-shadow. Since then, only the unprefixed version is supported." Found this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) in the Notes sections. Does that help explain the behavior you're getting?

Comment: Yes, perfect. I upvoted you. It was really simple. Still I'm having problems with the second part of it, about the bad rendering of the shadow in FF, only when it has blur 0 and a rgba color. I enabled this option at my page, so if you scroll-down it, you will see how it gets darker at some point: http://compraralojamientoweb.com/blog/ (it's the main shadow of the boxed layout).

Comment: I think that is a well know optical illusion, kind of like how square A and square B are actually the same color in this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2WPIY.png)

Comment: I found it! Working on localhost and disabling the JS files one by one, I discover that the sticky menu is generating a conflict. Now I only need to find where and why and I will fix it.

Comment: Thank you, Alejandro. I'm planning to use a shadow without alpha, because I inserted this shadow in 4 boxed templates with sticky menus (Avada, Inovado, Priority...), and I could see this issue in all of them, always in Firefox. When I disable the sticky menu of my WordPress theme, or also boxing the twentythirteen theme, the render is perfect. It seems that the renderer of FF generates temporary layers of the shadows when an element has `position:fixed`, and these layers appear when the scroll-down arrives at the vertical position of the object. It's rare, rare.